# Redirect domain request to different vm machines

Tags: redirect, dns, vmware

Is it possible somehow to redirect domains to vm machines. I only got 1 ip-address and also would like to use ports twice. Is there some kind of application that could handle this?

Lets say:

domain1.com:80 -> vm machine 1

domain2.com:80 -> vm machine 2

Any chance of sending the request to the host and let the host decide which vm machine the request should go to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With "1 ip-address" you mean 1 public ip-address, right? The two VMs surely have unique (private) IPs, havn't they?

If you can create a third VM you could install an Apache HTTP server and use [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) and [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_http.html): The virtual host at domain1.com would proxy to VM 1 and the one at domain2.com would proxy to VM 2.